# Function from site.js not loaded before page js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I am having the issue that my JQuery validation method is failing with the error:

> TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined

The problem is the function regex inside of my validate function.

I load following Javascript inside of _Layout.cshtml:

```html
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/js/dark-mode-switch.min.js"></script>
```

In my BT_ChallengeResponse.cshtml I call following scripts:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js" defer></script>
    @* <script src="~/js/site.js" defer></script> *@
    <script src="~/js/BT_ChallengeResponse.js" defer></script>
}
```

In the site.js is following function:

```
$.validator.addMethod('regex', function(value, element, param) {
    var error = [];
    var lines = value.split('\n');
    //console.log("Value: " + value);

    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        
        if( (lines[i].trim().replace(/:/g,'').replace(/\./g,'').replace(/-/g,'').replace(/ /g,'').match(typeof param == 'string' ? new RegExp(param) : param)) == null){
            error.push(lines[i]);
        }
    }

    if (typeof error !== 'undefined' && error.length > 0) {
        console.log("Error by follwing entries: " + error);
        return this.optional(element) || false;
    } else {
        return this.optional(element) || true;
    }
  },
  'Please enter a value in the correct format.');
```

The validation method is called from BT_ChallengeResponse.js:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function () {
//$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form_code").validate({
        errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
        rules: {
            input_code:{
                required: true,
                regex: "^\\d{8}$"
            }
        },
        
        messages: {
            input_code: "Please enter a valid code (eg: 1234 5678)."
          
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).removeClass('is-valid').addClass('is-invalid');
            },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
                //$(element).removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
                $(element).removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('form-control');
            }
    });
});
```

When I move the regex function to BT_ChallengeResponse.js it is working fine, but shouldn't it also be running like that? The site.js is loaded before the BT_ChallengeResponse.js but it feels like that the function regex is null.

I put the regex method in the site.js because I am reusing it in another view, but there I also have no issue.

Comment: This issue needs to be debugged, and we need to confirm whether it is a duplicate load of javascript files, or a problem with multiple jquery versions. So please create a demo that reproduces the problem so that it is possible to find the problem. Please don't forget to hide your sensitive information.